# Removing custom post type slug but WordPress keeps redirecting it

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, slug

So I'm trying to remove the custom post type slug at the start of the URL. I can get my rewrite to work but WordPress keeps redirecting it back to the URL I don't want.

At the moment this is the URL structure:

/projects/project_1

but I want:

/project_1

I've tried this solution:
https://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/

When your in the dashboard and hover over the view button its the right URL but when you visit it WordPress redirects it to the unwanted URL.

I've tried several other solutions but no luck.

Any ideas how to stop WordPress redirecting it?

Also just to confirm I've refreshed the permalinks each time and still the problem happens.

Comment: I recall that there's an option to "resync permalinks" in the WP admin settings, maybe it would help?

Comment: I've reset the permalinks each time and still no luck

Comment: Maybe in your functions.php file, you have a custom_post_type function that creates that slug mechanism?

Comment: At the moment its not set so goes to default